# Is there an app for crowdsourcing Wifi zones?

Tags: wifi, app, travel

Sometimes when I travel I run out of mobile data.  Other times my phone network just doesn't work in the foreign country.

In these instances I have to run around looking for a WiFi spot where I can sort things out, usually tickets, bookings, video calls with family, etc.  Important stuff.

The problem is that you often need to pay for something to get access to WiFi, and on more than one occasion, the WiFi would then turn out not to work or to work too slowly.

I was looking for something like a crowd-sourced map of WiFi zones in big cities, but couldn't find such an program on various app stores or on GitHub.

The idea would be: an app providing the locations and quality scores of complimentary WiFi spots in an urban area.  Optionally, users could crowd-source passwords for the WiFi zones.  Access to WiFi zone passwords could be allotted based on an in-app currency, earned by submitting and validating WiFi zones in other areas.  Basically like SE's kudos system.

This would also be of huge benefit to homeless individuals.